# Processing.js - Error when canvas is placed in div

Tags: canvas, processing, processing.js

I'm trying to get a canvas that is using Processing.js to appear fullscreen, but if I put the canvas into a div to get it to stretch fullscreen or center align it or do anything interesting, then the Processing.js throws an error saying the canvas has no style defined.

```
oldCursor = curElement.style.cursor,
```

This is the line throwing the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cursor' of undefined".

In the below section, the same code is applied to each canvas and the only difference I can see, is that the canvas is a child element?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="processing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example of bug</h1>
    <script type="application/processing" id="sketch">
    void setup(){
      size(1280, 720);
      noFill();
      smooth();
      frameRate(50);
      background(255);
      strokeWeight(2);
    }

    void draw(){
        stroke(0,244,244/4);
        ellipse(5,10,52,52);
    }
    </script>
    <!-- Canvas Element -->
    <canvas style="text-align:center; cursor: pointer; background-color: red; z-index:     0; margin:  0px; padding: 0px;" width="1280" height="720" id="canvas">You do not support     canvas.</canvas>     
    <div>
        <canvas style="text-align:center; cursor: pointer; background-color: blue; z-    index: 0; margin:  0px; padding: 0px;" width="1280" height="720" id="canvasbug">You do not support canvas.</canvas>     
    </div>

    <!-- Sketch Initializer -->
    <script type="text/javascript">    (function () {
            var init = function () {
            // This works fine
            var canvas = $("#canvas");
            canvas.css("background-color", "pink");
            var sketch = $("#sketch").text;
            canvas.css("background-color", "orange");
            new Processing(canvas, sketch);
            canvas.css("background-color", "green");

            //This is bugged
            var canvas = $("#canvasbug");
            canvas.css("background-color", "pink");
            var sketch = $("#sketch").text;
            canvas.css("background-color", "orange");
            new Processing(canvas, sketch);
            canvas.css("background-color", "green");
        }
        addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
    })();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing a canvas element, you're passing a jQuery object.  If you do:

```
var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
...
var canvasbug = $("#canvasbug")[0];
```

You'll get the raw elements.

Comment: passing in the raw element throws no error, and it gets to the final test (sets bg to green.. which would clear if processing takes over)  but processing doesn't seem to start rendering?